# Do I have to use init before require in composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am bit confused about commands `composer init'` and `composer require`

If I am correct:

- If I would like to add a library to my project from packagist I need to use `require`
- If I would like to publish my library to packagist I need to use `init`

I have a project and I do **NOT** want to publish it to https://packagist.org/

I just want to add some libraries to my project.

Do I have to necessarily run `composer init` before I run `composer require`?

I watched a tutorial, where they use `composer init` command before calling `composer require`, which confused me, because I though that `composer init` was related to publishing a library on packagist.

Comment: `composter init` just generates a default `composer.json` file. The same file also gets generated when you install the first depency using `composer require ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`composer init` just creates an "empty" `composer.json`, asking you some questions to fill out boilerplate.

No, it's not a necessary command "to publish a package", just a helper to initialize a project. That project can *either* be an package or stand-alone project.

`require` adds a package to an existing `composer.json`, and if the `composer.json` file does not exist in that directory it will just creates a blank one for you.

So calling `composer init` is certainly **not** required before running `composer require package-name`, but it simply helps you have a more fleshed out `composer.json` to start with.